# Symlinking metro.config breaks from Expo SDK 44 to 46. How to symlink in 46?

Tags: expo, symlink

I started a new mobile app project and since we have our own mobile components for reusability, we also use symlinking from the local component to the Expo app to make sure it's being developed properly.  We have successfully linked prior Expo apps using SDK `44`, but in this new project, we decided to use the most recent `46`.  It seems when [I update the `metro.config` file](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/monorepos/#modify-the-metro-config) the same as before, the bundler crashes.

default metro.config

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
const path = require('path');

// const workspaceRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../myComponentLib');  // this gets uncommented when using a link
const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.transformer.babelTransformerPath = require.resolve(
  'react-native-svg-transformer',
);

const assetExts = defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts;
const sourceExts = defaultConfig.resolver.sourceExts;

defaultConfig.resolver = {
  assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== 'svg'),
  sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
};
defaultConfig.resolver.nodeModulesPaths = [
  path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
  // path.resolve(workspaceRoot, 'packages/mobile/node_modules'), // this gets uncommented when using a link
];
// defaultConfig.watchFolders = [path.resolve(workspaceRoot)]; // this gets uncommented when using a link

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

When I use the `metro.config` like above, it's fine.  But if I uncomment the 3 lines notes, it fails.  The error I get is:

[image: symlink failure]

I am curious, is there a difference in linking between the different SDKs now?

Comment: Does it have anything to do with React Native versions between component lib linking into the actual Expo app?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, the reason for this is hidden well inside the docs: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/monorepos/#modify-the-metro-config

Scroll down to the section:

> Why do we need to watch all the files with the monorepo?

Their example to watch scoped package names does the trick:

```
// If your monorepo tooling can give you the list of monorepo workspaces linked
// in your app workspace, you can automate this list instead of hardcoding them.
const monorepoPackages = {
  '@acme/api': path.resolve(workspaceRoot, 'packages/api'),
  '@acme/components': path.resolve(workspaceRoot, 'packages/components'),
};
```